# How to avoid making almost identical inheritance

Tags: python, oop, inheritance

I have a class `OnlineState` that should set up a client and connect to a server, and also function as a game state (menu, pause, store, etc..). I want that if there isn't a server yet then the class will create the server and then connect to it. I already have a `Client` class and a `LocalClient` class that inherits `Client` and works. I could create an `OnlineStateClient` and `OnlineStateLocalClient` classes but I plan these classes to be inherited a lot and this approach will cause identical code. This is my code:

```
class Client:
    def __init__():
        # Connects to the server

class LocalClient(Client):
    def __init__():
        # Creates a server
        Client.__init__(self)  # connects to it

class OnlineState(Client, State):
    def __init__(local):
        if local:
            # connect
        else:
            # Create a server and connect
```

What can I do to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Sorry for not focusing language, this contains just an opinion for same issues.

Interface is your friend and separation of concern is the main title of oop. Client and localclient should have same methods and properties. 
You can manage state with this two with interface.

You may use client factory to create local client or online client.
You need to use another class to manage connection state line statefactory.
OOP is not just inheriting classes one to other, it is also using similarities to live together.

```
interface IClient
    def __init__():
        # Connects to the server
    def __State__() => clintState
class Client:IClient
    def __init__():
        # Connects to the server
    def __State__() => clintState



class StateFactory(IClient):
    def __init__(local):
        switch IClient.state
        case online:
            # do nothing 
        case  local:
            # Iclient = new Client(connProp)
        default :
```

Hope helps and i suggest you to check creational design patterns

Comment: kocakmstf. There are no interfaces in python. See http://masnun.rocks/2017/04/15/interfaces-in-python-protocols-and-abcs/

Comment: Sorry i just missed it is phyton, just focused on oop. I'm not familiar to pyton but it should have something else with same functionality for it. It can be protocol or even abstract class also can do similar things.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to make "OnlineStateClient" inteface and OnlineStateLocalClient Interface instead of using classes.Since in Interfaces you just need to declare the methods and don't get bothered about the definiton of method.So there won't be an issue of identical code and you can inherit it as many times as possible.

Comment: How would there not be identicle code if I will write the connection part each time I inherit the interface? Currently it's an abstract class.

Comment: Can you please explain me in more depth why are you creating these two new classes??

Comment: Which two new classes are you referring to?